# How do I change global fontSize as per media query in React Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, themes, material-ui, user-experience

I am trying to change the `fontSize` (which is 14 by default as per documentation). I wanted to make it 18 if my display is full HD (i.e: 1920*1080 or '@media screen and (max-width: 1900px)'). So I believe that will change other all typography fonts which are in "rem" which are based on this typography global `fontSize`.

I had even tried applying media query in my themeOveride js.

```
const themeOverrides = {
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'Ubuntu, sans-serif',
    '@media screen and (max-width: 1600px)': {
      fontSize: 16
    },
    '@media screen and (max-width: 1900px)': {
      fontSize: 18
    }
  },
}
```

But it's not working as per condition.

Comment: It does not seem to be possible to change base `fontSize` this way. Docs [say](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes) that you can change "theme.typography.* variant" because its "properties map directly to the generated CSS". Hope I'm wrong)

Comment: Take a look at [`responsiveFontSizes`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#responsivefontsizes-theme-options-theme), worked out for me

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is true, but you should put it inside a brace pair:

```
const themeOverrides = {
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'Ubuntu, sans-serif',
    ['@media screen and (max-width: 1600px)']: {
      fontSize: 16,
    },
    ['@media screen and (max-width: 1900px)']: {
      fontSize: 18,
    },
  },
};
```